# htaccess redirect to shared SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a question fitting my exact circumstances.

I am redesigning a site, part of which will require SSL coverage. I have set up SSL with our hosting provider, but this is shared SSL. Whereas our current site is at `www.companyname.com`, the secure server is at `companyname.genericssl-host.com`.

I believe the best way to proceed is to simply shift all the web files onto the secure server, whether they need to be secure or not, then redirect `www.companyname.com` to there. However, the provider informs me that if I do that, the URL in the browser address bar will still read `companyname.genericssl-host.com` once the redirect completes, and that I would need to edit the htaccess file to make it read good ol' `www.companyname.com` again.

What does the htaccess file need to contain in order to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your hosting provider is referring to, but changing it back to "www.companyname.com" defeats the purpose of using SSL at all. What shows up in the browser's address bar is:

1. what host the browser is going to send a request to
2. what URI it will request
3. the query string if there is any

If you change it *back* to `www.companyname.com`, it's going to send a non-SSL request to that host, which defeats the purpose of redirecting it to SSL in the first place.

You need to buy a certificate for `*.companyname.com` and install if on a host specific to your server.